# Combine blocks of sp spatial data into a single block

Tags: r, r-sp

I have 8 shape files each containing the outlines of many river catchments. I've used a combination of rgdal, rgeos and sp to read these and form a list of 8 SpatialPolygonsDataFrame objects. The code I used is as follows:

```
unit.num <- c(13,18,19,29,41,75,79,80)
GetCatchmentShapes <- function(x) {
  file.name <- paste("GFMUnit",x,"_GFES_Watersheds_WGS84.shp",sep="")
  con = file.path(project.folder,"RawData","Watersheds","GFES Watersheds",file.name)
  catchment.list <- readOGR(con,ogrListLayers(con)) 
}
all.catchments <- sapply(unit.num, GetCatchmentShapes)
```

How can I combine the 8 elements of `all.catchments` into a single SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object?

Comment: Do they all have the same set of fields?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they do. They don't have a unique identifier though. The Label field is just 1 to the number of catchments in each list entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `spChFIDs(...)` function in package `sp` to change the polygon IDs to unique values, then use `rbind(...)` to combine the spatialPolygonDataFrame objects.

Here is an example using the shapefiles for France, Italy, and Germany.

```
## example dataset; shapfiles for France, Italy, Germany
## you have this already...
library(raster)
FR <- getData("GADM",country="FRA",level=1)
IT <- getData("GADM",country="ITA",level=1)
GR <- getData("GADM",country="DEU",level=1)
spList <- list(FR,IT,GR)    # list of country shapefiles

# you start here...
library(sp)   # loaded with `rgdal`
set.IDS <- function(sp,i) spChFIDs(sp,paste(i,rownames(sp@data),sep="."))
result  <- do.call(rbind,mapply(set.IDS,spList,seq_along(spList)))
plot(result)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this method of ID-creation is much more sensible than my approach!

Comment: Thanks, this has worked. Not related, but possibly useful, I had to rename the fields of one of the blocks where I assume the GIS generation process had inconsistently capitalized one field - always worth checking. Once this was fixed, jlhoward's method worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit messy, and there's likely a better way to create unique row IDs, but here goes anyway:

Assuming your list of `SpatialPolygonsDataFrames` is called `spdf_list`, and that all elements have the same set of fields:

```
spdf_list <- 
  mapply(spChFIDs, spdf_list, 
         split(as.character(seq_len(sum(sapply(spdf_list, length)))), 
               unlist(mapply(rep, seq_along(spdf_list), 
                             each=sapply(spdf_list, length)))))

single <- do.call(rbind, spdf_list)
```